# Can PowerShell (or script) on Windows / Mac / Ubuntu list file / directory structure easily?

Tags: unix, powershell, ubuntu, macos, shell

Can PowerShell on Windows by itself or using simple shell script, list files and directory this way:  (or using Mac OS X or Ubuntu's shell script)

```
audio
  mp3
    song1.mp3
    some other song.mp3
  audio books
    7 habits.mp3
video
  samples
    up.mov
    cars.mov
```

Unix's `ls -R` or `ls -lR` can't seem to list it in a tree structure unfortunately.

Comment: The question is not completely clear. PowerShell runs on Windows; how would you get on Windows the result of a script running on Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use tree.com for listing like indented like shown above.  Note that tree.com only works with the filesystem.  If you ever have a need to display structure for other providers like WSMan or RegEdit, you can use the Show-Tree function that comes with the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com).

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, you can use:

`ls -R directory | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'`

or for the current directory:

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

You can put this "small" command in a script: [look here](http://www.centerkey.com/tree/)

Comment: hm... actually, don't know why but it doesn't work on Ubuntu 10.04... oh it seems to list only the folders, not individual files...

Comment: You're right, it shows only folders. It could be modified to show files too but I think you're better using the tree command suggested. I didn't knew it when I suggested this command line... Tree works perfect on Lucid and list files. (obs: you can use only "tree" or "tree folder", no need for ls -R before).

Answer (score 1):

you can use Unix's tree command, or if you are on Windows, the [GNU windows tree](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/tree.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a tree command:

```
C:\folder>tree . /F
Folder PATH listing for volume sys
Volume serial number is F275-CBCA
C:\FOLDER.
│   file01.txt
│
├───Sub folder
│       chart-0001.png
│       chart-0002.png
└───────chart-0004.png
```

The /F parameter is what tells it to show files.  You can execute this from Powershell

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
ls -R | tree
```

It's not installed by default on Ubuntu.  So, to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install tree
```

Comment: tree doesn't take input from `ls -R`.  you can `echo hello | tree` and achieve the same effect.